# How to get Wifi RSSI level with NDK JNI in Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, wifi, rssi

does someone have an example or can show how it works to get Wifi RSSI level with NDK JNI in Android?
I have to compare the rssi level from java code vs JNI.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I am able now to get a String from a cpp file.

File:
com_example_cvlab_ndktest_NativeClass.cpp

```
#include <com_example_cvlab_ndktest_NativeClass.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
Java_com_example_cvlab_ndktest_NativeClass_getMessageFromJNI
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj){
  return env->NewStringUTF("This is a message from JNI");
  }
```

com_example_cvlab_ndktest_NativeClass.h:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_cvlab_ndktest_NativeClass */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_cvlab_ndktest_NativeClass
#define _Included_com_example_cvlab_ndktest_NativeClass
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_example_cvlab_ndktest_NativeClass
 * Method:    getMessageFromJNI
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
Java_com_example_cvlab_ndktest_NativeClass_getMessageFromJNI
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

NativeClass.java
    package com.example.cvlab.ndktest;

```
/**
 * Created by zafaco on 14.06.2017.
 */

public class NativeClass {
    public native static String getMessageFromJNI();


}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_cvlab_ndktest_NativeClass.cpp

    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
    LOCAL_MODULE := MyLibs


    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
    APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
    APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
    APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

This works fine for me.
So now how I can call methods from other librarys?
For example I found [Link1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/618455f/core/jni/android_net_wifi_Wifi.cpp#377) and [Link2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e2d281/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiNative.java#379)
and I am interested in RSSI

Answer (score 0):

The input of the method is a command to send to the wifi driver. Try:

```
res = android_net_wifi_getRssiHelper("SIGNAL_POLL");
```

To get more control over the command and response, you can send the command manually via:

```
doCommand(const char *cmd, char *replybuf, int replybuflen);
```

where `cmd` is your command.

For a list of possible commands you can use see:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e2d281/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiNative.java

Comment: I tried  res = android_net_wifi_getRssiHelper("SIGNAL_POLL");  I get this error: Cannot resolve method 'android_net_wifi_getRssiHelper(java.lang.String)'

Comment: that was a native method which you should use in c. are you looking for a java api?

Comment: No sorry. You are right. I will try it later when I am home again. Thank you so far!

Comment: I think I have to learn a bit about c++. I guess I need some days. For example I dont know atm how to get res to my java code after I put your portion of code in my c++ class. I get this error atm. : Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_com_beispiel_wlanorhan_WifiConnections_rssiFromJNI less... (Strg+F1) 
Reports native method declarations in Java where no corresponding JNI function is found in the project.

Comment: @Okey technically speaking, you can also use reflection to call the WiFiNative.java methods instead of using native code.

Comment: Maybe you can give me an example with native rssi? I would really appreciate that!!

Comment: Maybe you can look into again? I have updated my question. @SoroushA